# Getting tag names of first block of xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a very big xml in which a block keep repeating.Now I want only the tag names of first block.I'm poor in xsl.I tried but in vain.Please anyone help.
My xml is as show below,

```
<catalog>
<product>
<title>GATE MCQ For Electronics &amp; Communication Engineering</title>
<originalprice>Rs 680</originalprice>
<sellingprice>Rs 680Rs 530</sellingprice>
<discount>22% Off</discount>
<payment>Cash on delivery available</payment>
<review/>
</product>
<product>
<title>Gate Guide Computer Science / Information Technology (with CD)</title>
<originalprice>Rs 695</originalprice>
<sellingprice>Rs 695Rs 480</sellingprice>
<discount>31% Off</discount>
<payment>Cash on delivery available</payment>
<review/>
</product>
```

The product block keeps repeating but with different values.
My xsl which I'm using now is,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns="http://www.java2s.com"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema"
            version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="//*[local-name() = 'product'][1]/*">

<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output am getting is,

```
    title
    originalprice
    sellingprice
    discount
    payment 
    review 


   Gate Guide Computer Science / Information Technology (with CD)
   Rs 695
   Rs 695Rs 480
   31% Off
   Cash on delivery available
```

But required output is,

```
    title
    originalprice
    sellingprice
    discount
    payment 
    review
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you need to start your template from the root (by matching '/') and then limit the elements you want to have processed using 'apply-templates', like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns="http://www.java2s.com"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema"
            version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/product[position() = 1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      <xsl:text>
      </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this will produce the desired output...

Answer (score 2):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="product[1]/*">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<catalog>
    <product>
        <title>GATE MCQ For Electronics &amp; Communication Engineering</title>
        <originalprice>Rs 680</originalprice>
        <sellingprice>Rs 680Rs 530</sellingprice>
        <discount>22% Off</discount>
        <payment>Cash on delivery available</payment>
        <review/>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>Gate Guide Computer Science / Information Technology (with CD)</title>
        <originalprice>Rs 695</originalprice>
        <sellingprice>Rs 695Rs 480</sellingprice>
        <discount>31% Off</discount>
        <payment>Cash on delivery available</payment>
        <review/>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
title
originalprice
sellingprice
discount
payment
review
```

Answer (score 1):

`"//*"` is "all nodes starting from root", you probably want more restrictive XPath like "/catalog/product/*" (or similar with `local-name` function if you don't want to handle namespaces properly).